# Extracting information from <script> using Beautifulsoup! Python

Tags: python

I'm new here and i hope you can help. I'm learning Python for a while now and I'm currently practicing web scraping.

I have tried beautifulsoup which worked until I was hit by this script. I have used a beautify website to make it readable.

```
<div class="uq-hide js_variationsJSON">
            </div>  
    <div class="pdpStage__column pdp__details js_pdp-details">
         <script>
          var pdpVariationsJSON = 
        
        {
            "color-COL05|size-SMA002": {
                "id": "419994COL05SMA002000",
                "attributes": { "color": "Gray", "size": "XS" },
                "availability": { "status": "IN_STOCK", "statusQuantity": "0", "inStock": true, "ats": "19", "inStockDate": "", "availableForSale": true, "purchaseLevel": "", "levels": { "IN_STOCK": 1, "PREORDER": 0, "BACKORDER": 0, "NOT_AVAILABLE": 0 }, "isAvailable": true, "inStockMsg": "1 Item(s) In Stock", "preOrderMsg": "0 item(s) are available for pre-order.", "backOrderMsg": "Back Order 0 item(s)" },
                "pricing": {
                    "showStandardPrice": false,
                    "isPromoPrice": false,
                    "standard": 59.9,
                    "formattedStandard": "£59.90",
                    "sale": 59.9,
                    "formattedSale": "£59.90",
                    "salePriceMoney": {},
                    "standardPriceMoney": {},
                    "pricePercentage": "",
                    "quantities": [
                        { "unit": "", "value": 0 }
                        ]
                },
                "applicablebadges": [
                    { "id": "extendedSize", "value": "global.badge.extrasize", "coValue": "XXS-3XL", "class": "grey" }
                    ]
            },
            "color-COL05|size-SMA003": {
                "id": "419994COL05SMA003000",
                "attributes": { "color": "Gray", "size": "S" },
                "availability": { "status": "IN_STOCK", "statusQuantity": "0", "inStock": true, "ats": "24", "inStockDate": "", "availableForSale": true, "purchaseLevel": "", "levels": { "IN_STOCK": 1, "PREORDER": 0, "BACKORDER": 0, "NOT_AVAILABLE": 0 }, "isAvailable": true, "inStockMsg": "1 Item(s) In Stock", "preOrderMsg": "0 item(s) are available for pre-order.", "backOrderMsg": "Back Order 0 item(s)" },
                "pricing": {
                    "showStandardPrice": false,
                    "isPromoPrice": false,
                    "standard": 59.9,
                    "formattedStandard": "£59.90",
                    "sale": 59.9,
                    "formattedSale": "£59.90",
                    "salePriceMoney": {},
                    "standardPriceMoney": {},
                    "pricePercentage": "",
                    "quantities": [
                        { "unit": "", "value": 0 }
                        ]
                },
                "applicablebadges": [
                    { "id": "extendedSize", "value": "global.badge.extrasize", "coValue": "XXS-3XL", "class": "grey" }
                    ]
            },
```

Everytime I get a result of None or a whole code but without this bit. I'm not sure why.

Here is how I call it

```
req = Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
link= mylink
w = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(w, "html.parser")
new = soup.find('div',{'class':'pdpGrid pdp__module pdpStage js_pdpGrid js_pdpGrid-    no-quickview'})
print(new)
```

I would appreciate any advice

Here's the link as an example to the website:
'https://www.uniqlo.com/uk/en/product/men-ultra-light-down-jacket-419994COL09SMA005000.html'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have the website so it's hard to know exactly what's going on, but I would imagine the script tag you are seeing is generated through a request upon loading the page.

Since javascript is not executed by requesting the page, it will not show up.

I would suggest looking at the "Network" tab in your browser's debugger menu to try and track down where it's coming from.

Then you would need to make a request to that page and likely parse the JSON response.

Edit: So basically I'm going to take a leap here and say: good luck but it's going to be damn near impossible to scrape. First, everything is dynamically generated via javascript, second, they use akamai (anti-scraping technology) along with browser fingerprinting. Basically trying to scrape something like is threading a needle through an invisible maze of requests with dozens of keys and parameters.

Most I could get you was this info [here](https://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/batch.json?passkey=care9DOHHRfHvGUp8OUHNrJrDetImNzF4bpkO9wkCHUpM&apiversion=5.5&displaycode=0588-en_gb&resource.q0=products&filter.q0=id%3Aeq%3A419994&stats.q0=reviews&filteredstats.q0=reviews&filter_reviews.q0=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Aen_EU%2Cen_US%2Cen_GB&filter_reviewcomments.q0=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Aen_EU%2Cen_US%2Cen_GB&resource.q1=reviews&filter.q1=isratingsonly%3Aeq%3Afalse&filter.q1=productid%3Aeq%3A419994&filter.q1=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Aen_EU%2Cen_US%2Cen_GB&sort.q1=submissiontime%3Adesc&stats.q1=reviews&filteredstats.q1=reviews&include.q1=authors%2Cproducts%2Ccomments&filter_reviews.q1=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Aen_EU%2Cen_US%2Cen_GB&filter_reviewcomments.q1=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Aen_EU%2Cen_US%2Cen_GB&filter_comments.q1=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Aen_EU%2Cen_US%2Cen_GB&limit.q1=8&offset.q1=0&limit_comments.q1=3&callback=BV._internal.dataHandler0) if you are able to access that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Here's the link to the website  'https://www.uniqlo.com/uk/en/product/men-ultra-light-down-jacket-419994COL09SMA005000.html'   I will still try to do what you suggested

Comment: Updated my original post, TLDR it's a major pain in the ass to scrape.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aero this is so helpful to know. I'm new to webscrapping and I wanted to practice but it seems that I'm out of my depth. Thanks any way for your help. Much appreciated! I can access the link, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely loaded by javascript after the fact. As Aero Blue mentioned, you can look for the location that it's originally coming from, or if you can do that, you can try Selenium. Selenium helps handle webpages that have running javascript.

Comment: I actually did try selenium and it didn't really work. I followed a tutorial online but it didn't work with the website. 'https://www.uniqlo.com/uk/en/product/men-ultra-light-down-jacket-419994COL09SMA005000.html'

Comment: Oh yeah that's definitely loaded in post. Use the direct method with the network tab and then get the link that's directly called.